# Se repite evento keydown con Jquery, al usar tecla rapida

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Saludos cordiales. Resulta que utilizo la siguiente funcionalidad de tecla rapida:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
        $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function (event) {

         //codigo bla bla
         alert("ejemplo");

      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

era tecla(cualquier tecla para todos los casos), me muestra tres veces el alert.

Es como si algo estuviera acumulando los eventos de tecla rápida keydown para que se repita.

Pero lo mas extraño, al hacer la misma acción de prueba, no sucede siempre, otras veces no da este problema.

Tendría que limpiar el keydown o declararlo de otra forma?Alguna idea??

Comment: Pon un poco más de código, así a simple vista no se puede saber mucho la verdad y puede que el código "blablabla" importe. De todas forams mirate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605296/document-onclick-not-working y la documentación oficial http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

He estado probando tu snippet y solamente muestra el `alert` una vez.

¿En que contexto utilizas esta función? ¿Es posible que el script se esté cargando más de una vez? De ser así, asociarías más de un evento al `document`. El comportamiento sería similar a esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   
  $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function (event) {

    //codigo bla bla
    alert("ejemplo");

  });
  
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   
  $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function (event) {

    //codigo bla bla
    alert("ejemplo");

  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que uso un MasterPage, que trae vistas parciales, y el codigo del problema es una vista parcial

Comment: lo solucione añadiendo $(document).off('keydown', 'body'); antes de $(document).on('keydown', 'body', function (event) {, pero dentro del document ready